# How can I show folder and its subfolders from server to Silverlight application in TreeView?

Tags: silverlight

How can I show folder and its subfolders from server to Silverlight application in TreeView?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add support for this on the server side. Either:

- Add a web service that safely returns the folder and subfolders and files
- Have the web page that the Silverlight plugin is in add this information into the HTML of the page (that can be read like an XML island) or the initParams of the object tag.

There is no way to do this in just the client.